# Cannot find module 'copy-webpack-plugin' when building a Docker image in github actions

Tags: docker, webpack, dockerfile, github-actions

I am trying to build a docker image from a github action workflow

I have a Dockerfile that looks like this :

```
FROM node:16 as build

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

ARG NODE_ENV

ENV NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV

RUN npm ci \
  && npm run build:$ENVIRONMENT // only fails when running npm run build:production in github action

FROM nginx:alpine as main

COPY nginx/nginx-frontend.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY --from=build /app ./

EXPOSE 80
```

This image is properly building locally, but when I try to build it in github actions, it fails with the error :

```
#19 51.35 [webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'copy-webpack-plugin'
#19 51.35 Require stack:
#19 51.35 - /app/frontend/webpack.config.js
#19 51.35 - /app/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
#19 51.35 - /app/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
#19 51.35 - /app/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
#19 51.35 - /app/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
#19 51.35     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:15)
#19 51.35     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:873:27)
#19 51.35     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)
#19 51.35     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18)
#19 51.35     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/frontend/webpack.config.js:2:20)
#19 51.35     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
#19 51.35     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
#19 51.35     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
#19 51.35     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
#19 51.35     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19) {
#19 51.35   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
#19 51.35   requireStack: [
#19 51.35     '/app/frontend/webpack.config.js',
#19 51.35     '/app/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js',
#19 51.35     '/app/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js',
#19 51.35     '/app/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
#19 51.35     '/app/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
#19 51.35   ]
#19 51.35 }
```

my github-action step looks like this :

```
- name: Build and push frontend image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          context: .
          file: Dockerfile.frontend
          push: true
          tags: frontend:latest
          build-args: 
            NODE_ENV=production
```

I've already tried different node & npm versions, but nothing helps : my build works fine on my local machine but not on github-action VM
Weird thing is that if I build the image on a github action VM with `npm run build:staging` it also works ...

I have in my package.json :

```
"build:staging": "NODE_ENV=staging webpack --config frontend/webpack.config.js --progress --color --mode=production",
"build:production": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config frontend/webpack.config.js --progress --color --mode=production",
```

If anyone has an idea it would help a lot !

Thanks !!

Comment: It is very strange, I worked around it with a dirty change by changing `NODE_ENV=production` to `NODE_ENV=prod` and the build works fine on the github action VM ...

I have the feeling that it might be linked to the webpack config that takes absolute paths in my case, but this is only a guess